# expl3 clist does not make comma separated lists from variables

Tags: expl3

I'm trying to make a comma separated list, but have noticed some strange things occurring. Here's an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand{\assignment}{1, 2, 7, 8}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\getitem}[2]
{\clist_item:nn {#1}{#2}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getitem{\assignment}{1}

\getitem{1, 2, 7, 8}{1}

\end{document}
```

What ends up being outputted is "1, 2, 7, 8" on the first line and "1" on the second. I want to "contain" the comma list within a variable to make it easier to change, as I'm using this for a template.

But, it seems that by putting the list in a variable, clist loses its ability to separate the list by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your definition, you are executing

```
\clist_item:nn { \assignment } { 1 }
```

which of course delivers `\assignment`.

You want

```
\clist_item:Nn \assignment { 1 }
```

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix. In general, what's the difference between "Nn" and "nn" after the colon?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Yes. But there is a fundamental difference between the two call in the code above, because in the first case the comma list consists of a single item, in the second case of four.